# SimpleIOC and generics

Tags: c#, generics, simpleioc

I'm trying to generalize some code so that it can be used between projects, but I'm having some trouble generating instances from templated classes.

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext, new ()
{
    protected TContext Context;

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        Context = new TContext();
    }

    public virtual TEntity Create()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Create();
    }

    // etc.
}

public interface IPlan
{
    int PlanId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    DateTime Created { get; set; }

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}

public partial class Session : DataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged, IPlan
{
    // Stuff to implement IPlan
}
```

IPlan and Generic repository are in the common code base, and Session is project-specific. So I want to be able to do something like this:

```
   // These both work correctly
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IPlan, Session>();
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IGenericRepository<Session>, GenericRepository<Session, EMTVSEntities>>();

   // Tried this one ...
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IGenericRepository<IPlan>, GenericRepository<Session, EMTVSEntities>>();
```

Ultimately what I want is to be able to call this last one and get the context like this ...

```
var ctx = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IGenericRepository<IPlan>>();
```

But I get the following message: Unable to cast object of type 'GenericRepository`2[Session,EMTVSEntities]' to type 'IGenericRepository`1[IPlan]'.

I understand it can't match the two types to do a case, but is there a way to get a specific instance from one identified by an interface using the templated type GenericRepository?

Comment: what library are you using? GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc?

Comment: Yes,  GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc

Comment: I would consider switching to a different IOC framework if it accomplishes what I need to do, though.